# Need help to convert REST call in PHP to ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have some PHP code that make REST call for sending SMS to phone as the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['number'])){
$api_key = 'api_key';
$api_secret = 'api_secret';
$curl = curl_init('http://domainname.com/sms/format/json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key.':'.$api_secret);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'sender'=>$_POST['from'], 
            'unicode'=>0, 
            'body'=>$_POST['sms'], 
            'phone'=>$_POST['number']
            'keyid'=>'123456'
             ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

}

How can we convert this code to ASP.NET with C#?

Comment: The [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes can be used to do the same action as cURL. There are plenty of tutorials for doing such requests using these classes and the documentation is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work. Note you need .net 4.5 for this:

```
      const string api_key = "ap";
      const string api_secret = "as";
      using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
      {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", api_key, api_secret))));
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sender", this.Request.Params["from"]), 
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("unicode", 0),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("body", this.Request.Params["sms"]),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("phone", this.Request.Params["number"]),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("keyid", 123456)
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://", formContent);
  }
```